# Typing quickly breaks umlauts

Tags: spacemacs

If I am in no-window-mode (`emacs -nw`) and type e.g. the word “für” quickly, the “ü” is replaced by other characters. This does not happen in window mode, and it does not happen for any other character preceding the umlaut, only an *f*.

```
Quickly: fÃ\274r
Slowly: für
```

When I try to save, emacs tells me that

> utf-8 cannot encode these: \274

For *för* I get a `\266`, and *fär* creates a `\244`. The first two characters, *fü,* write `fÃ`, and the next character then adds the `\274` plus the typed character, like *r.*

I am using a Swiss German keyboard where äöü are separate keys. `Ctrl-h l` shows the following output:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: How do you type those chars (do you have a key for them on the keyboard, or is there some key-combo or key-sequence for them)?  Also you might like to look at `C-h l` which should show you the actual data that Emacs received and might give you a clue about what's going on.

Comment: @Stefan, I have added the information to the question, thanks for the hint about `Ctrl-h l`!

Comment: Sounds like something to report as a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Here, I expect that the only help you can get is the suggestion to type slower. But perhaps someone will have a better suggestion.

Comment: I agree with Drew: this looks like a bug in a fairly deep part of Emacs.  You might like to try and check whether the problem also happens with `emacs -Q` and if not, try and find which part of your config triggers this bug (and include that info in your bug-report).

Comment: How quick/slow are we talking about? I presume that this *only* happens in Emacs -- other terminal applications do not have the same issue? If you have another terminal emulator installed, does the same thing occur under that?

Comment: @phils Exactly, only in Emacs, nowhere else. Around 5 characters/s, so I have to type quite slowly to avoid it.

Comment: @Stefan Okay, with `-Q` it works – then I should probably report a bug at Spacemacs. Finding out which config is responsible is probably out of scope for here (as is the question, probably, since it is not the intended behaviour …)

Comment: I think I know what could be the underlying problem, so please put me in "Cc:" when you submit your bug report.

Comment: @Stefan I will, if you tell me how :D (I assume the [bug tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues) is the correct place)

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster: good question.

Comment: @Stefan Oh, I just recall there is this concept called *hyperlinks* in the word-wide web! Issue on GitHub: [Typing quickly breaks umlauts #10259](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/10259)

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster: Spiffy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was/is a bug in [evil-escape](https://github.com/syl20bnr/evil-escape) which is a package to get back to normal state by pressing `fd` *quickly* anywhere. It can be disabled by adding `evil-escape` to the exluded packages variable in `~/.spacemacs`.

```
dotspacemacs-excluded-packages '(evil-escape)
```

More details can be found in the corresponding [bug report for Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/10259).